# Quotes reported with "It might be said"

Tags: passive-voice, quotations

I know that the following examples are sound:

> Someone might say: "I am very smart".
>
> The following might be said: "I am very smart".
>
> It might be said that I am very smart

knowing that the last one has a different meaning because "I" refers to the narrator rather than someone being quoted.

But does the following example look linguistically sound?

> It might be said "I am very smart".

or with a colon

> It might be said: "I am very smart".

Comment: Asking if it "looks linguistically sound"...  not the first one, but the second with a colon could be ok, but that's like using a hammer to put a pushpin into styrofoam - a bit of overkill but not incorrect.

Comment: I'd label both 'ungrammatical'.

Comment: @3m3sd1 This is a _colon_ **:**

Answer (score 1):

You are using "it might be said" in an unidiomatic manner.  It is not normally used with a direct quote. Usually it is complemented by a *that*-clause.

> It might be said that it takes a village to raise a child.
>
> It might be said that possession is nine-tenths of the law.
>
> It might be said that the party has become a disunity of factions whose interests are incompatible.

Comment: To expand your excellent answer, the OP may consider using **"One might say"** instead of **"It might be said that"**